# Can't maximize window fully?

Tags: windows-7, display

I'm in stock Windows 7, and something has happened such that I can't maximize windows fully. The Maximize operation functions, but behaves as though the top X pixels of my display aren't relevant. I can see my desktop behind the window, and I can drag restored windows into that space, etc.

What can I do to again be able to use my entire display when maximizing windows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlock your taskbar, move it to the top of your display, and then return it to the bottom of your display.

[Source](http://www.sevenforums.com/general-discussion/176426-window-wont-maximize-fully-2.html#post1509682)

Comment: Is this what you did to resolve the issue?

Comment: Yes. Surely it's a solution to a niche problem that hasn't adequately been defined.